# Undesirable need of double run for effect with click on basic JS to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

Im new to development, and for some study practices Im doing this vanilla JS that prints to DOM Dice Roller.

The main idea is for the user to input the number of sides and the number of dice, press a roll and gets all the dice results and the sum on the DOM.

It is working, but I cant figure out why **I need to click twice** for the event to happen, any tips, please?

http://codepen.io/rufi_rufino/pen/MKdrbj

```
//Variables

var form = document.getElementById('mytest');
var sideField = document.getElementById('sides');
var numberField = document.getElementById('numbofdices');
var numberOfSides = 0;
var numberOfDice = 0;
var arrayOfResults = [];
var resultOfSum = 0;


//to get dice data (sides and # of dices) form html forms - Using .preventdefault() to stop from sending form and staying with result;

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
//to get the value of the number of sides the dice has:
    numberOfSides = (sideField.value);
//to get the value of the number of dices in the game:
    numberOfDice = (numberField.value);    
    e.preventDefault();

});



//Basic Functions

//function to calculate a result and create the array of all results
function createArrayOfDice () {

    for (i = 1 ; i <= numberOfDice ; i++) {

        var result = 0;
        result = Math.floor((Math.random() * numberOfSides) + 1);
        arrayOfResults.push(result);

    }

}

// function to sum the results of all dice
function sumOfAllDices() {

    // the line below "resets" the output if user clicks more than once
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = " ";

    for (i = 0 ; i < arrayOfResults.length ; i++) {


        resultOfSum = resultOfSum + arrayOfResults[i];
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML + "<div class='diceroll'>" + arrayOfResults[i] + "</div>";

    }

    console.log(resultOfSum);
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = "<div class='dicesum'>" + resultOfSum + "</div>";
    resultOfSum = 0;

}

//function that works when user clicks the 'Roll' submit button on html
function myClick () {

    createArrayOfDice();
    // for console purpose(see if it is wokring)
    console.log(arrayOfResults);
    sumOfAllDices();
    // for console study only
    console.log ("The input number for how many sides the dice has is:" + numberOfSides);
    console.log ("The input number for the number of dices is:" + numberOfDice);
    arrayOfResults = [];

};
```

If anyone could help, I appreciate. This is my first question as well, if I made any mistake, I would be glad to take it in consideration.

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem

Comment: The problem is probably a side effect of all your code depending on *global state*. To fix it, pass around and return the values you want your code to work with. Though for a script that does so little, you might as well just go with less functions overall. The following might help you, but as it's basically a complete rewrite, I'm not sure it's good fit for an answer. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxgpqY

Comment: thank you, it really helped!